# Strange layout constraints with UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I just met a strange issue about strange UITableViewCell subclass layout.
I had configuring an `UITableViewCell` subclass with all of this stuff in code.

- iPhone 5s and lower  **WORK PERFECT**

[image]

- iPhone 6 or plus     ***WRONG :(***

[image]

I am sure that is the subclass issue.

```
(lldb) po _tableView
<UITableView: 0x7fa5db054c00; frame = (0 0; 375 618); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa5d96649e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa5d96632a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 15552}>
```

**Code:**

```
@interface ColorCell : UITableViewCell

@end 

@implementation ColorCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    self.background  = [UIView new];
    self.top         = [UIView new];
    self.bottom      = [UIView new];

    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.background.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
    self.top.       translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
    self.bottom.    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.background];
    [self.background addSubview:self.top];
    [self.background addSubview:self.bottom];

    self.top.backgroundColor        = [UIColor purpleColor];
    self.bottom.backgroundColor     = [UIColor blackColor];

  }
  return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];
    if (!self.didSetupConstraints) {

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_firstColor,_secondColor,_thirdColor,_fourthColor,_fifthColor,_background,_top,_bottom,_title,_stars,_favourites);

    NSString *format;
    NSArray *constraintsArray;
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"topHeight":@100.0, @"bottomHeight":@50};

    format = @"V:|[_background]|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    format = @"H:|[_background]|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    format = @"V:|[_top(topHeight)][_bottom(bottomHeight)]|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary];
    [_background addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    format = @"H:|[_bottom]|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [_background addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    format = @"H:|[_top]|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [_background addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    self.didSetupConstraints = YES;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x7fa91341ce00; frame = (0 0; 375 667); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa91341b290>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fa91341c610>>
| <UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fa913703e70; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa91343f400>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913702480>>
|    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x7fa913621e80; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa91361d7e0>>
|    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x7fa9159678d0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa91343f150>>
|    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa913441190; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913443820>>
|    |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0x7fa913841400; frame = (0 0; 375 618); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa91342f520>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913435060>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 15582}>
|    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7fa913445200; frame = (0 0; 375 618); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa913440320>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa9134319d0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 618}>
|    |    |    |    |    |    | <ColorCell: 0x7fa913637230; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 600; 375 150); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa9136375b0>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7fa913637630; frame = (0 0; 375 150); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa913637960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913637700>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa9136379c0; frame = (0 0; 324 150); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913637a90>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa913638730; frame = (0 0; 324 100); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913638800>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa913637ab0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913637b80>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa913637ba0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913637c70>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa913637c90; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913637d60>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa913637d80; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913637e50>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa913637e70; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913637f40>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa913638820; frame = (0 100; 324 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa9136388f0>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7fa913637f60; frame = (8 8; 240 34); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fa913636920>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UILabelContentLayer: 0x7fa9135b5ba0> (layer)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fa913638290; frame = (256 25; 17 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa913638390>>
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7fa9136383b0; frame = (281 -100; 35 0); clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fa913638510>>
```

Strange Point:
**If I removed `self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` and it works perfect. But the strange issue is warnings on constraints raised.**

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b9764e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fad5b971a20(44)]>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b976fb0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fad5b971db0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fad5b971a20 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b976db0 V:[UIView:0x7fad5b971db0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fad5b971a20 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b9763c0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fad5b972b70]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fad5b971db0 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b977730 V:[UIView:0x7fad5b972b70(100)]>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b976410 V:[UIView:0x7fad5b972b70]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fad5b972c60]>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b9777b0 V:[UIView:0x7fad5b972c60(50)]>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b977800 V:[UIView:0x7fad5b972c60]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fad5b971db0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5b976410 V:[UIView:0x7fad5b972b70]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fad5b972c60]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You're focusing on the cell, but I wonder if the problem is the constraints of the tableview, itself. What do its constraints look like? Use the new [view debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014509-SW7) in Xcode 6, or run the app, pause execution, and at the `(lldb)` prompt, type `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` and see what the frame of the table view, itself, is.

Comment: You might also check out `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` to make sure you don't have any warnings on your constraints.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not getting this auto layout error when I tried your code. The only way I can this is by implementing a conflicting `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` or setting `rowHeight` to 44.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to     `self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` since that wasn't created programmatically. Also, you need to call `[super updateConstraints]` at the END of the override, not the beginning.

EDIT to include errors (from comments below): What's happening here is the UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height is the iOS 8 constraint created for the self-sizing cell. After the cell is created, if constraints are modified you will get this error. There are a few ways to manage it; in this case, I was going to mention anyway that since you only need to add the constraints one time, try adding the constraints not in updateConstraints but in the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier.

The issue is more subtle, and a new problem with iOS 8: at some point your tableView thinks the row height is 44, so it creates a constraint the set cell height to 44. After this you add these constraints, but the tableView doesn't recalculate the height, so you get the errors. If, as @Rob notes above, you are setting the height to 44 somewhere that would do it. It won't solve your problem is some constraints are telling the tableView height should be 44, but regardless you could should set estimatedRowHeight to 150, since that looks like a safe estimate, or if they are all definitely going to be 150 just set rowHeight to that.

Comment: I added all constraints programmatically. I removed `self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` and work perfect. But the **strange** issue is  warnings on constraints raised.

Comment: Autolayout warnings are usually strange, can you edit the question include them.

Comment: What's happening here is the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` is the iOS 8 constraint created for the self-sizing cell. After the cell is created, if constraints are modified you will get this error. There are a few ways to manage it; in this case, I was going to mention anyway that since you only need to add the constraints one time, try adding the constraints not in `updateConstraints` but in the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier`.

Comment: I tried you method. But no luck. The `self.didSetupConstraints` is what it means to forbid something to be modified. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The issue is more subtle, and a new problem with iOS 8: at some point your tableView thinks the row height is 44, so it creates a constraint the set cell height to 44. After this you add these constraints, but the tableView doesn't recalculate the height, so you get the errors.

Comment: You are exactly right. I fixed this by changing `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method and errors gone. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I finally work out the reason about the constraints warnings.

I removed `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method and the warnings disappear.

So the answer is clear: I should not do something about **constraints updating** in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Instead, I just return the rowHeight, then problem fixed.

Comment: @Rob Thanks sooooo much. You are exactly right. I  should accept the answer both of you. Cheers!